# How to use notepad++ to Extract 4 digit numbers from a string of numbers

Tags: notepad++

Assuming that I have string:

```
[(3749.0, 77.19), (3699.0, 86.11), (3648.0, 90.87), (3623.0, 81.35), (3608.0, 88.06), (3601.0, >97.73), (3576.0, 79.31), (3558.0, 84.12), (3551.0, 94.65), (3525.0, 82.88), (3511.0, 87.48),
(3500.0, 97.57), (3450.0, 91.18)]
```

How can I get output of those first sets of 4 digit numbers:

```
3749.0
3699.0
3648.0
3623.0
etc.
```

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Do this :

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Go to the Mark tab
- Enter "Find what" : `\b\d{4}\b` and ensure "Regular expression" is selected.
  To also select the digit after the dot, use the expression
  `\b\d{4}\.\d\b`.
- Press Mark All
- Press Copy Marked Text
- Paste the clipboard to a text document to have all the selected numbers,
  one per line.

[image]

Comment: works great Thank you!

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\[|\G).*?\((\d{4}\.\d)(?:, \d+\.\d+\)\])?`
- Replace with: `$1\n` or `$1\r\n` depending on platform
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **TICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:\[|\G)       # non capture group, opening square bracket OR restat from last match position
.*?             # 0 or more any character, not greedy
\(              # opening parenthesis
(               # start group 1
    \d{4}           # 4 digits
    \.              # a dot
    \d              # a digit
)               # end group 1
(?:             # non capture group
    , \d+\.\d+      # a comma, a space, 1 or more digits, a dot, 1 or more digits)
    \)              # closing parenthesis
    \]              # closing square bracket
)?              # end group, optional
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @flybuzz: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)